Kinesis Consumer Library... how to replicate proper streaming behaviour?
I'm using the AWS Kinesis Consumer Library with Python.
My application streams records from a Kinesis Data Stream. The data consists of events from various web applications.
These batches of events are then organised by "customer", formatted/modified, then asynchronously sent as POST requests to a third-party SaaS product's API.
It is based on this example provided by AWS. In fact the only real change is that, instead of logging the processed records, my application does some bits with the data and then sends it to the aforementioned API:
        events_by_customer = self.get_events_by_customer(events_batch)

        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
            processes = []
            for uid, customer in events_by_customer.items():
                payload = gzip.compress("\n".join(customer.events).encode("utf-8"))
                processes.append(executor.submit(self.send_api_request, customer=customer, payload=payload))

What I'm finding is that my application isn't exhibiting what I see as typical streaming/consumer behaviour: instead of the "average age of a record" growing (e.g. the "queue backing up") and the records taking longer to be processed... they're just getting dropped.
For example, if we get ~5K/min records going on to the Kinesis stream, and my application is performing at 3K/min requests being sent, those other 2K/min records just... disappear. Like KCL considers them processed, but they've never actually gone anywhere.
If my application is capable of performing at 5K/min or more, then nothing gets dropped.
What I'm trying to understand therefore is how KCL works in this respect. How does it consider a record processed? Is it as soon as the API call is made to Kinesis to retrieve the record? I know it's not like SQS where once a message is "pulled", it's no longer available, so presumably KCL makes the call then records its checkpoint in DynamoDB to say "don't process this batch of records, I've already done it".
Is there some "blocking" mechanism I can put in place to stop this data from being lost? If it takes longer to process (as this is often batch data which only gets sent once/week) then that's fine - but losing the data is obviously a huge concern.
Thanks
